# What is the best way of inserting a datetime value using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

What is the best way of inserting a datetime value using a dynamic sql string, whilst at the same time being able to handle the possibility of the value being null?

The current statement inserts into a table from a select statement built using a string.  The datetime value is stored in a parameter and the parameter is used in the select.

Like so:

```
SET @execsql = 'INSERT INTO ( start_date )
SELECT ( ''' + CAST(start_date as VARCHAR) + ''' + ')'
EXECUTE(@execsql)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're running Sybase something like

```
Set @execsql = 'Insert Into <table> ( start_date ) Select (' + 
  Case When start_date is null Then
    'Null' 
  Else 
    '''' + Cast(start_date as Varchar) + '''' 
  End + ')'

Execute(@execsql)
```

Should do the trick

Here's the SQL Server way for reference

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(max), @params navarchar(max)

Set @sql = N'Insert Into Table (start_date) Select (@start_date)'
Set @params = N'@start_date datetime'

Exec sp_executesql @sql, @params, @start_date
```

Obviously, in this case you wouldn't need dynamic SQL, but I assume this is part of a larger example.

As always with dynamic SQL questions, http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html is recommended reading.

Comment: This is part of a larger example that is using dynamic sql inside an sproc, so the parameters are stored inside. I'm using EXECUTE() too.

Comment: @jaffa Thought as much, the answer I wrote still uses dynamic sql, though. Is there any reason you can't use sp_executesql instead of execute? (The only one I can think of is that this is an old version of SQL Server that doesn't have it)

Comment: I'm actually using Sybase and the sproc I am modifying is legacy code.

Comment: fair enough, added a version that should work with Sybase, although I have no way of testing it.

Comment: This looks more like it.  I'd have to create a stringParam version which is then embedded into the larger sql statement. Do you know if this is the best of way of doing this?  Or could TomBom's version be used?

Comment: TomBom's will never insert a null, instead a default value.